# How to resolve this exception invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'SprayJsonSupport.class'

Tags: scala, unit-testing, akka

I'am using

```
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

scalacOptions := Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-encoding", "utf8")

libraryDependencies ++= {
  val akkaV = "2.4.18"
  val scalaTestV = "2.2.6"
  val akkaHttpV = "10.0.10"
}
```

I tried to run my test cases but it's showing error like this

```
  Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'SprayJsonSupport.class'.
    Could not access type FromByteStringUnmarshaller in package akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.package,
    because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
    missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
    A full rebuild may help if 'SprayJsonSupport.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.package.
```

How can I resolve this can suggest here, please.
 Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the latest spray Json dependency, also update your Akka-test kit version, sbt and scala version.

As you are using marshaller and unmarshaller
To convert your case class into json and vice versa. 
I think it should solve your problem.

```
libraryDependencies += "io.spray" %% "spray-json" % "1.3.1"
```

Add this in your dependency it’s compatible with Scala 2.11.x

But I would suggest you to update all your dependency with the new ones.